# tslint-loader with webpack 2.1.0-beta.25

Tags: typescript, webpack, tslint, webpack-2

I have an angular2 Project that I compress/compile with webpack.

I use tslink loader with webpack so I have tslint related configuration in `webpack.config.js`.

```
module.exports = {
...
tslint: {
    configuration: {
        rules: {
            quotemark: [true, "double"]
        }
    },

    // tslint errors are displayed by default as warnings
    // set emitErrors to true to display them as errors
    emitErrors: false,

    // tslint does not interrupt the compilation by default
    // if you want any file with tslint errors to fail
    // set failOnHint to true
    failOnHint: true,

    // name of your formatter (optional)
    formatter: "",

    // path to directory containing formatter (optional)
    formattersDirectory: "node_modules/tslint-loader/formatters/",

    // These options are useful if you want to save output to files
    // for your continuous integration server
    fileOutput: {
        // The directory where each file"s report is saved
        dir: "./webpack-log/",

        // The extension to use for each report"s filename. Defaults to "txt"
        ext: "xml",

        // If true, all files are removed from the report directory at the beginning of run
        clean: true,

        // A string to include at the top of every report file.
        // Useful for some report formats.
        header: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<checkstyle version=\"5.7\">",

        // A string to include at the bottom of every report file.
        // Useful for some report formats.
        footer: "</checkstyle>"
    }
},
...
preLoaders: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loader: "tslint"
        }
    ],
}
}
```

I updated webpack 1.13.1 to 2.1.0-beta.25 and tslint configuration breaks the complication process of `npm run build`.

I changed the `preLoaders` directive to `loaders`

```
module: {
        ....
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loader: 'tslint',
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            enforce: 'pre'
        },
    ],
}
```

that's not enough cause I still get the error

```
For loader options: webpack 2 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
 Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
```

so I should move the tslint configuration and place it somewhere else. kinda lost here. so any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

For others who have problems with preloaders in webpack 2. In beta v2.1-beta.23 there are breaking changes with pre/postLoaders.

First the "loaders" section should be renamed to "rules". Also pre/postLoaders is now defined under rules.

In my case i was using tslint as a preLoader. To add a pre/postLoader to rules add the `enforce` property with value either `pre` or `post`.

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            enforce: 'pre',
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            loader: 'tslint',
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        },
        {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader'],
            exclude: /(node_modules)/
        }
    ]
}
```

More info in the release on github: [Webpack v2.1.0-beta.23](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v2.1.0-beta.23)

In the release info there is also a link to a [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/2237/files) that shows the needed changes going from `v2.1.0-beta.22` to `v2.1.0-beta.23`  in webpack config file. There you can see that you also need the LoaderOptionsPlugin.

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        options: {
            tslint: {
                emitErrors: true,
                failOnHint: true
            }
        }
    })
]
```

Comment: Awesome answer.Can I use node_modules without the parenthesis?Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

ok.. so I just needed to move the `tslint` definition under:

```
plugins: [
    new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        options: {
           tslint: {
             ...
```

and declared

```
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require("webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add a plugin, you can do something like this,

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      enforce: 'pre',
      test: /\.ts$/,
      loader: 'tslint-loader?' + JSON.stringify({
        emitErrors: true,
        failOnHint: true
      })
    }
  ]
}
```