# WebPack 2: Migrate preLoaders and postLoaders

Tags: webpack

I've installed `webpack@2.1.0-beta.27`. Before, I was using `webpack@2.1.0-beta.22`. On my configuration file I was using `preLoaders` and `postLoaders`:

```
preLoaders: [
    {
      test: /\.ts$/,
      loader: 'string-replace-loader',
      query: {
        search: '(System|SystemJS)(.*[\\n\\r]\\s*\\.|\\.)import\\((.+)\\)',
        replace: '$1.import($3).then(mod => (mod.__esModule && mod.default) ? mod.default : mod)',
        flags: 'g'
      },
      include: [helpers.root('src')]
    },

  ],
  loaders: [...],
  postLoaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'string-replace-loader',
      query: {
        search: 'var sourceMappingUrl = extractSourceMappingUrl\\(cssText\\);',
        replace: 'var sourceMappingUrl = "";',
        flags: 'g'
      }
    }
  ]
```

I'm not able to figure out once I've took a look on internet how to migrate this `preLoaders` and `postLoaders`.

Should I put them inside `loaders`? Only that?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From v2.1-beta.23 the loaders section is renamed to rules and pre/postLoaders is now defined under each rule with the `enforce` property.

I've answered in more detail in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39919793/tslint-loader-with-webpack-2-1-0-beta-25/39997947#39997947)

More info can also be found in the [release notes](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v2.1.0-beta.23) on github

The release notes also mentions a [migration example](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/2237/files) in the angular cli repo

Another tip is to look at the [json schema](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/schemas/webpackOptionsSchema.json) that validates the config for hints.